# An etched border around a box

Tags: html, css

I have a box where I've created an "etched" vertical line by placing a `#bbb` line and an `#fff` line next to each other with the CSS:

```
div#product_details_separator {
    height:100px;
    width:0px;
    border-left:1px solid #bbb;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
```

Etched Vertical Line:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can give the entire border around the box this same etched effect?

Comment: Could you post the HTML/CSS? It'd be a lot faster if I don't have to do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `box-shadow` to achieve that etched effect. [**See the DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/q4z9cL6n/1/)

CSS

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do sounds kind of like the inset border-style, that may be worth looking into.  To add a second layer of border, however, you can use the outline property.  This allows you to specify an outline that goes directly around the border.

```
border: 1px solid #bbb;
outline: 1px solid #fff;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several interesting (and seldom used) styles to set on a border [w3c doc](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding#The_border-style_properties)

Combining them, you can achieve several interesting variations on your request

Notice that the grayed color is calculated automatically. See also the 4th example, to achieve special effects different from the standard ones

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}  
.one {
  border: groove 20px lightblue;
}
.two {
  border: ridge 20px lightgreen;
}
.three {
  border: inset 20px tomato;
}
.four {
  border-top: groove 20px tomato;
  border-left: groove 20px tomato;
  border-right: ridge 20px tomato;
  border-bottom: ridge 20px tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```